# why is transformer not considered as an amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, transformer, electrical

I know that in a transformer the power is conserved on both sides, and hence there's no power amplification as such. That's fine!

But if I instead want only a voltage amplification, then choosing proper turns ratio and connecting the load across the secondary would serve my purpose. So can you consider it as voltage amplifier? If yes, then why is it not used as one?

Comment: Yes, a transformer can be used to amplify (verb) voltage, but it's not an amplifier (noun).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a subtlety of the terminology. If there's no (capability of) power amplification, then we don't call it an "amplifier" even though the output voltage might be higher than the input voltage.

As others have pointed out, there are other functional differences between transformers and amplifiers, one being that power can flow both ways through a transformer but generally only one way through an amplifier.

Finally, we already have a word for a device that can change voltages without providing power gain, so we don't need to call these things *amplifiers*. We can just call them *transformers*.

Comment: besides the subtleties of terminology, can we use transformer as a voltage amplifier? or does it pose any challenges?

Comment: You can use a transformer as a transformer. You can't use it for what we usually call an amplifier because it doesn't provide power gain. If your system doesn't require power gain, then you might be able to use a transformer instead of an amplifier but that doesn't mean you're using the transformer *as* an amplifier.

Comment: May I ask why should a (voltage) amplifier HAS to provide power gain?

Comment: So, in voltage amplification applications, can I use transformers instead of the commonly used BJTs/MOSFETs?

Comment: Maybe you mean voltage through an amplifier, power doesn't usually flow through an amp, they usually require more power to amplify

Comment: You can, under certain limited conditions, use transformers to step up voltages.  But note that I use the term "step up", not "amplify".  However, the frequency range over which this will work is limited, and it puts constraints on the output impedance of the source connected to the transformer, and the input impedance of the sink that the signal is going to.  Back in the early days of vacuum tubes, transformers were often less expensive than tubes, and were commonly used for step-up in audio applications.  That sort of practice was already falling out of favor in the 1940's, though.

Comment: A voltage-amplifier provides a predictable Vout, even as the Rload changes. Thus changes in I_load are not expected to require more input signal energy. If the voltage-gain is +ONE, we call those Buffers, with the purpose of providing lots of output current.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Vout will be the same irrespective of load.

Comment: @Viki, it's not a matter of whether a particular device has to provide some capability. We just use one word to label one kind of device and a different word to label a different kind of device. For example, maybe in some circumstance I can use my sedan to carry some goods across town. But that wouldn't change my sedan into a delivery truck. It would just be using a sedan to do a job that could also be done by a delivery truck. If I had a larger load of goods to deliver, the sedan might not be able to do the job and might need to get an actual delivery truck.

Comment: Whether you can use a transformer in an application that normally uses transistors depends entirely on the details of that application. In a very small set of circumstances (pure AC signal, loading effects not important, power gain not required, etc., etc.,) you might be able to substitute a transformer for a transistor. In general though you would not be able to substitute.

Comment: @ThePhoton I understand your point. All I'm concerned is about it's "capabilitiy" as you mentioned. I don't care if it's sedan or a truck as long as it's an automobile.

Comment: @Viki, sadly there isn't a catch-all term like "automobile" that applies to both transformers and amplifiers. If you want to talk about both together as a group for some reason you'll have to say "transformers and amplifiers".

Comment: @TimWescott The bandwidth issue is there with conventional amplifiers like BJT and other devices too, right?

Comment: @Viki, "bandwidth" has two sides. Many transistor circuits work down to DC. No transformer will work down to DC.

Comment: @Viki I think it's time for you to stop asking and start experimenting.  If you actually do some work on this you'll find that the bandwidth restrictions on transformers are much more severe than on semiconductor (or even late-day vacuum-tube) amplifiers.  It' easy-peasy to make a transistor amplifier that works from DC-100kHz, and not impossible to do it with 12AX7's.  Getting a "Hi-fi" frequency range of 60-20,000Hz from a small-signal step-up transformer is expensive, bulky, and prone to all sorts of odd parasitic effects.

Comment: The possible reason I give myself for now is that the primary side which has the low voltage source cannot sustain the high current that would arise because of the  constant power constraint. 

While, in the case of transistor based amplifiers, the current would also be low along with the low voltage, so the source side circuit is not severely affected.

So, IMO transformer not being used as an amplifier has more to do with practical constraints rather than anything else.

(ofcourse, Transformers will have a hard time working at lower frequencies)

Comment: Larger cores and more turns of wire are, as far as I know, the key to low-frequency transformer success. And what is the meaning of "the constant power constraint"?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf for an ideal transformer, input power = output power. I meant to say that, therefore, the current drawn will be inversely proportional to the voltage level.

Answer (score 1):

Only for ideal transformers, power is conserved.
Real transformers have losses, which may be load dependent. So, in that case, the 'output' voltage is not the gain times the 'input' voltage.

For voltage amplifiers, you also want them to have unlimited (or at least large) current supply. This unlimited current is needed, so the output is not dependent to the load, i.e. the voltage should not collapse because of the load.
For transformers, this 'output' current is dependent and limited.

Comment: why should it have this "large current" requirement? All it has to provide is higher voltage and it does the job pretty well, right?

Comment: @Viki I updated to answer your question.

Comment: Here, the secondary voltage is independent of load. it's only determined by the turns ratio, irrespective of the kind of load.
(It's assumed that I'm talking about AC analysis only for obvious reasons)

Comment: What if you use a 0 ohm resistor as load? Or 1 ohm? You likely need to put quite some power into an *ideal* tranformer to have the voltage remain gain*input_voltage. Moreover, for an real transformer, with such load, the load's resistor will be in the same order as the coil windings, causing a current dependent voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

Amplifiers typically provide input-output isolation. Changes in output energy need not require more input energy (tho the VDD rail must support the output demands)

A transformer of course does not provide isolation.

Comment: Completely reverse ….a transformer provides isolation an amplifier typically does not.

Comment: @JackCreasey two different kinds of isolation.

Comment: I was considering the S21 style of energy flows.

Comment: Then you have to define what you mean ….given the question posed by the OP you'd need a very detailed description.